# Adicionar script em post

Tags: wordpress

Estou criando um site free no https://wordpress.com/

Minha intenção é adicionar códigos, e para isto, gostaria de usar o [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/)

Minha tentativa foi adicionar através do CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.10.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Tentei adicionar diretamente no post, mas não obtive resultados!

Gostaria de saber como posso incomporar estes scripts nos posts?

Comment: Acho pouquíssimo provável que o wordpress.com permita publicar scripts aleatórios no conteúdo, mas eu perguntaria aqui: https://br.support.wordpress.com/

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski tentei descrever lá de uma forma simples. Depois me fala o que achou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

não é possível adicionar scripts externos no WordPress.com.

Para adicionar códigos, recomenda se o uso do shortcode `[code]`.

Exemplo:

```
[code language="css"]
your code here
[/code]
```

Pode se ler mais sobre este [shortcode](https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) (em inglês).